# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Help me

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

The application works with 8-inch tablets and more, but does not work with smaller tables add some dimens.xml(480, 600, 720, 840), add some devices with different version of android (kitkat, lollipop) works with 8-inch screens.

no entiendo de puede estar el error, si es un error de tamaños o algun linearlayout le falta algun atributo

this is my error

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=-10066331
 at android.text.StaticLayout.getLineTop(StaticLayout.java:850)
 at android.widget.TextView.getDesiredHeight(TextView.java:6481)
 at android.widget.TextView.getDesiredHeight(TextView.java:6452)
 at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6421)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1226)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1226)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
 at android.view.Choreographer$Cal
```

Comment: It is very very long, send to mail???